# Post user comments to company Facebook page using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The marketing department at my company has requested a text box on the home page of one of our microsites that will allow a user to post a comment directly to our Facebook page. I've been able to sort out how to the wall of the user, and I can in theory see how to post to our page, but I cannot seem to find a way to allow the user to post to our wall as the user. Has anyone out there had experience doing this? Is it even possible?

As a backup plan, I can default to posting to the users wall. I've got that working, but I want to tag our company page in the post. I've found several references to tagging users and pages, that seem to revolve around using the following format "@[pageId]", but that isn't working (the message just posts with the text @[pageid] and does not convert it to a link or a tag). The code I'm using looks like this

```
$post_id = $facebook->api('me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Hello world! @[pageid]'));
```

I've also tried adding "tags" and "places" to the array but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

"but I cannot seem to find a way to allow the user to post to our wall as the user"

as what else than the user should a user post to your wall, when not as himself?

First. Make sure that you have successfully requested the "publish_stream" permission.
If you have that, you're ready to go. I also noticed odd behavior when I tried to post on a fanpages wall via the FB-PHP-SDK. I tried a gain with curl and it was working as expected (altough it's been a while since I needed this, maybe it's working now via API).

**Note that if you're logged in to facebook with an account that has administrator on the page rights it will always post as the page**

```
$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/THE_PAGE_ID/feed";
$data['message'] = "I'm about to post something cool!";
$data['access_token'] = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN'; //Make sure you have requested the publish_stream permission

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thomas - I found your solution on another page, and I tried implementing it. I'm not getting any kind of error message, but it's not working either. I do have the "publish_stream" permission, but nothing shows up.

Comment: $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
 
$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/feed";
$data['message'] = "I want more cookies!";
$data['access_token'] = $access_token; //Make sure you have requested the publish_stream permission

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);